# Xcode 5-DP simulator says: 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'No class named 'id'

Tags: xcode5

When launching my app in Xcode 5-DP, in the simulator, I get the following exception:

```
-[AppDelegate application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:] [Line 47] Loading iPhone 5 nib
 *** Assertion failure in -[UIRuntimeOutletCollectionConnection performConnect], /SourceCache/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-2776.18/UIRuntimeOutletCollectionConnection.m:39
 *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'No class named 'id'.'
```

When I set breakpoints before loading the NIB, and in the viewDidLoad of the first view controller, the simulator runs fine.

It also doesn't always seem to happen, only sometimes. The NIBs were converted to the new format when Xcode asked me.

Comment: Xcode 5 and the iOS 7 SDK are currently under NDA - please use the Apple forums for such questions.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a development SDK/IDE that's currently covered by an NDA.

Comment: Oh please.... I'm always amused by the Apple puritans quoting the NDA. Apple dev isn't an exclusive membership you know. Google and Microsoft will have access, and I'm sure Apple are not going to get their lawyers onto Bart for asking this question. You're right, the question should be contained in the forums - but do you really have to get on your high horse to remind people?

Answer (score 1):

Well, I found the cause. For future reference:

https://devforums.apple.com/message/857071#857071

Comment: can you add the solution here please. The dev forums are down at the moment.

Comment: There were multiple labels linked to an outlet collection. I used that collection to hide a number of labels at once. To fix the above error, I just hide them one-by-one.